# Load MapView using AsyncTask Failed

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am trying to load a MapView in an `Activity` on a `button` is clicked but as it takes a little time to load the whole activity and in a way user feels that something got wrong.

So I tried to use `AsyncTask` but I am getting following Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            geoHandler=  new GeoUpdateHandler();

                    //Getting error over here 
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, geoHandler);

            return null;
        }


 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        mapController=mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16);                  
     }

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

                // first overlay
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);     
    }
```

I am unable to solve it.

Comment: you need to post a diffrent part of your code. what does it take long to load,and what do you do in onPostExecute() and onPreExecute()?

Comment: post your onPostExecute() and onPreExecute() code

Comment: you are using it wrong... you can't declare a Handler inside a non-UI thread. and also.. the `requestLocationUpdate` method will return immediately, and the handler or `LocationListener` will be called when location gets changed.

Comment: okay understood , but wht should i do as activity takes time to load

Comment: the same problem here, any suggestions how to load MapView/GoogleMap asynchroniously?

Comment: @Paulius i have two question for you 1) are you doing any operation in onCreate except loading mapView ? 2) how much your screen covers the google map ?